# PHP, Request time out and next request

Tags: php, curl

I have a foreach doing curl request, but some requests take more than 10 seconds to answer, I want to skip those requests, how is this done? I'm trying to set maximum 5 seconds per request if not responds then continue to the next request..

I tried setting timeout in curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
```

but I think that doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is in seconds, for miliseconds you need CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS

Comment: please publish the solution